# Create a subroutine in a VB.Net exe that is callable from another program

Tags: vb.net

Is it possible to create a subroutine in a VB.Net exe that is callable from another program(not VB.Net)? I am aware that you can do this with an assembly(dll), but can you do this in an exe as well?

[Edit]This VB.Net exe will already be running when called.

[Edit2] VB.Net program, these compile to become BA_SyncNet.exe - Form1.vb

```
Public Class Form1
    ...
    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        ...
    End Sub
End Class
```

VB.Net program - Helloworld.vb

```
Namespace MapInfoBA.MiProBA.SamplesBA
    Public Class HelloWorld

        Public Shared Sub SayHello(ByVal s As String)
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Hello, " + s)
        End Sub

    End Class
End Namespace
```

Calling program ba.mbx uses:

```
Declare Method SayHello Class "MapInfoBA.MiProBA.SamplesBA.HelloWorld"  Lib "BA_SyncNet.exe" (ByVal strName As String)

Sub Main()
    Call SayHello("World")
End Sub
```

Kind Regards

Comment: I believe the .net exe would have to be setup to accept command line arguments.

Comment: Hi @Jack, also forgot to mention that this VB.Net exe will already be running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am aware that you can do this with an assembly

**An .exe is a kind of assembly**.  So, yes.

Comment: Sorry @Joel Coehoom, when I say assembly I meant dll. Does that make a difference?

Comment: @Hank It doesn't change anything. A dll is also a kind of assembly. Basically, anything you can do with a dll, through COM or otherwise, you can do _because_ it is an assembly. And a .Net exe file happens to be an assembly also, just with a few special editions so that the runtime knows what to do when you double-click it.

Comment: Coehoom, thank you! Is it as simple as creating a new class within my App, if you look at my 2nd edit I just tried this with no luck. Any advice?

Comment: If both programs are .Net, you add a reference in Visual Studio from the caller and import the namespace, no need for a Declare directive.

Comment: Coehoom, the caller is written in MapBasic, very similar to vb6. "Declare Method" is used to call .Net assemblies. However with the above I get the error: Could not find class "MapInfoBA.MiProBA.SamplesBA.HelloWorld". Is there something I need to do to make this class or namespace COM friendly?

Answer (score 0):

Create a file (let's say, DoThisVBNet.txt) using MapBasic program.

Then your vb.net program checks the file from time to time.
The vb.net program will do a task (in your case, call a subroutine) based on the DoThisVBNet.txt file.

However,
Problem may occur on accessing the file since two programs are using it,
to fix this, use Registry instead of File.